VBA to determine remote desktop user
I would like to use VBA (64bit) to determine if a user is running VBA/Excel from a remote computer. For example, if PC#1 uses Chrome Remote Desktop (CRD) to remote login to PC#2, the VBA code on PC#2 would identify that a user was running it remotely. This ideally would work for Windows Desktop Connection (WDC), CRD, and other ways for users to remote login. Any suggestions?
Alternatively, what VBA code determines if WDC or CRD or others are currently in use?
Ideally, the “trust access to the VBA project object model” could stay unchecked.
Using ENVIRON$("SESSIONNAME") still shows "CONSOLE" on PC#2 when using CRD, so this did not work (it ideally would have shown “RDP” etc but did not). Others such as “username”, “computername” etc also did not help.
